# display only unique terms in a view from product in drupal commerce

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, view, commerce

I have a bunch of wines imported as products in drupal commerce and i want to make a 'regions' page to give a list of all the regions that is automatically populated by pulling the 'region' out of each product but that only displays unique values.

at the moment i have a list of all the products with the same region listed loads of times and i can't find a way in views to only show the regions once.

Comment: Did you try the distinct functionality in views?

Comment: what is the 'distinct' functionality?

Comment: Edit the view and go to Advanced > Query Settings > Distinct

Answer (score 0):

Try going to '**Settings**' under the 'Format' section of your view and setting your region as the '**Grouping field Nr.1**' -- you can then list the products from that region underneath or not....

============== EDIT ==================

If you don't want to display the wines under the terms, just start a new view from scratch, and when you're creating it, choose that you want to make this a taxonomy terms view, vs a content view.  That should do it!!

[image]

Comment: I don't want to display all the products just a list of the regions (taken from the products). Then once they pick a region the wines from that region will be displayed.

Comment: Unlessthere is someway of having a pull down menu in a sidebar that is populated by the region field item.

Comment: Alright.  I've edited my response then.  I think the second option would be more suitable for you....

Comment: sorry... how do i make the regions within the product become a taxonomy term?